# LNK4001 while still supplying obj files when building Python extension?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, python-3.x

I am porting my C Python extension to Python 3(.4.1) and Windows 7. I have the Windows 7.1 SDK (includes the VS 2010 tool chain) installed, and am getting linker error that appear to be incorrect. I have included the entire build process in the attached screenshot.

- LNK4001 warning occurs when there are no .obj files specified, but they are clearly visible in the command line.
- LNK1159 occurs when no output file is supplied, but /OUT:... is clearly visible in the command line.

Thanks!

[image: Compiler/linker commands and errors]

Comment: try to remove the final '\' from paths, i.e. instead of "c:\python34\lib\", try "c:\pythone34\lib".

Comment: Those paths are added automatically by python, but forcing their removal doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Correction, removing those paths do help. I'll post an official answer here for future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Houssam, removing the trailing '\' from the Windows SDK path fixed it.